# How to write CSS nth-child background color code in Python dash?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am creating a datatable in python dash. dbc.table couldn't change the color or striped row. I know in CSS we could use `tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #f2f2f2; }` to change the color. But how to use python style to write those codes?

Comment: Hope my answer was helpful. It would in turn be very helpful and much appreciated if you could also upvote the answer(s) and accept one of them if it ended up being helpful to you  ☮️ ✌️

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's how it's done with Dash DataTable (https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/conditional-formatting); they have some pretty powerful, cool conditional formatting CSS possibilities there:

```py
import dash
import dash_table
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

data = OrderedDict(
    [
        ("Date", ["2015-01-01", "2015-10-24", "2016-05-10", "2017-01-10", "2018-05-10", "2018-08-15"]),
        ("Region", ["Montreal", "Toronto", "New York City", "Miami", "San Francisco", "London"]),
        ("Temperature", [1, -20, 3.512, 4, 10423, -441.2]),
        ("Humidity", [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]),
        ("Pressure", [2, 10924, 3912, -10, 3591.2, 15]),
    ]
)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

df['id'] = df.index

app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    data=df.to_dict('records'),
    sort_action='native',
    columns=[
        {'name': 'Date', 'id': 'Date', 'type': 'datetime', 'editable': False},
        {'name': 'Delivery', 'id': 'Delivery', 'type': 'datetime'},
        {'name': 'Region', 'id': 'Region', 'type': 'text'},
        {'name': 'Temperature', 'id': 'Temperature', 'type': 'numeric'},
        {'name': 'Humidity', 'id': 'Humidity', 'type': 'numeric'},
        {'name': 'Pressure', 'id': 'Pressure', 'type': 'any'},
    ],
    editable=True,
    style_data_conditional=[
        {
            'if': {
                'column_id': 'Region',
            },
            'backgroundColor': 'dodgerblue',
            'color': 'white'
        },
        {
            'if': {
                'filter_query': '{Humidity} > 19 && {Humidity} < 41',
                'column_id': 'Humidity'
            },
            'backgroundColor': 'tomato',
            'color': 'white'
        },

        {
            'if': {
                'column_id': 'Pressure',

                # since using .format, escape { with {{
                'filter_query': '{{Pressure}} = {}'.format(df['Pressure'].max())
            },
            'backgroundColor': '#85144b',
            'color': 'white'
        },

        {
            'if': {
                'row_index': 5,  # number | 'odd' | 'even'
                'column_id': 'Region'
            },
            'backgroundColor': 'hotpink',
            'color': 'white'
        },

        {
            'if': {
                'filter_query': '{id} = 4',  # matching rows of a hidden column with the id, `id`
                'column_id': 'Region'
            },
            'backgroundColor': 'RebeccaPurple'
        },

        {
            'if': {
                'filter_query': '{Delivery} > {Date}', # comparing columns to each other
                'column_id': 'Delivery'
            },
            'backgroundColor': '#3D9970'
        },

        {
            'if': {
                'column_editable': False  # True | False
            },
            'backgroundColor': 'rgb(240, 240, 240)',
            'cursor': 'not-allowed'
        },

        {
            'if': {
                'column_type': 'text'  # 'text' | 'any' | 'datetime' | 'numeric'
            },
            'textAlign': 'left'
        },

        {
            'if': {
                'state': 'active'  # 'active' | 'selected'
            },
           'backgroundColor': 'rgba(0, 116, 217, 0.3)',
           'border': '1px solid rgb(0, 116, 217)'
        }

    ]
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[image]

Dash DataTable is very powerful and I would recommend it over dbc, but, if you do prefer and must use dbc, looks like something like this is how you would insert the CSS in Python:

```py
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "First Name": ["Arthur", "Ford", "Zaphod", "Trillian"],
        "Last Name": ["Dent", "Prefect", "Beeblebrox", "Astra"],
    }
)

table = dbc.Table.from_dataframe(
    df, 
    striped=True, 
    bordered=True, 
    hover=True, 
    css={"tr:nthChild(even)": "backgroundColor: #f2f2f2;"} # ← Maybe this will work?
)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Here is a solution which maintains use of the Dash `dbc` extra components library

> *(This answer is recommended unless you are willing to/interested in dropping use of `dbc`, in which case see my other answer which provides a solution using Dash's `data_table` principal table component):*

```py
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

from dash import dcc
from dash import html

import pandas as pd


app = dash.Dash(__name__)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "First Name": ["Arthur", "Ford", "Zaphod", "Trillian"],
        "Last Name": ["Dent", "Prefect", "Beeblebrox", "Astra"],
    }
)

table = dbc.Table.from_dataframe(
    df,
    # striped=True,
    # bordered=True,
    # hover=True,
    id="my-table", 
)

app.layout = html.Div([table])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True, dev_tools_hot_reload=True)
```

and then create an `\assets` folder in the directory where your app.py file is, and create a style.css file in that directory (you can name it anything, it's the `.css` ext which matters, and "assets" dir, Dash will automatically look for any custom styling there and allow it to override everything else), and simply put as you suggest:

```css
table#my-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #007eff7a;
}
```

You'll notice I also gave the table an "`id`" value.

[image: screenshot of desired even row styling]